# How to put file into clipboard without losing control characters?

Tags: command-line, windows, encoding

I have a `.txt` file originated from Windows, so its line endings are `\r\n`. Running `cat` or `echo` on that file makes those control characters go away. How can I display the file (even in raw bytes if possible) while preserving the original control characters from Windows?

Comment: `pbcopy < dosfile` and then `pbpaste > dosfile.copy` creates identical files, including the CRNL line endings

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks. Such a simple solution. If you submit an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pbcopy` will take input piped or redirected into it, and store it in a "pasteboard" (i.e. clipboard). So to copy a file verbatim, use a redirection:

```bsh
pbcopy < dosfile
```

To paste, use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> or

```bsh
pbpaste | some_command
pbpaste > some_file
```